# Windows FFMPEG concat from list and log each file inputted into to ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, windows

Ok i have a working batch file, where I grab from a text file a list of videos to concat as such

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 'dan_Ep_01HardWater.ts'
file 'dan_Ep_02GoldieTheGoldfish.ts'
file 'list2.txt
```

I then feed that to ffmpeg and display on ffplay at the same time using this code:

```
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Type in your stating playlist file
ECHO.

set /p list=""
ping localhost -n 2 >nul

set video=rtmp://stream.ssh101.com/live/test4589585
set stream=streaming.mp4

cls
color 70
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Encoding your RTMP stream now
ECHO.

bin\ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel quiet  -report -stats -re -f concat -safe 0 -stream_loop -1 -i %list% -flags +global_header -auto_convert 1 -c:v libx264 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -preset veryfast -b:v 1984k -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -tune zerolatency -vf "pp=hb/vb/dr/fq|8,crop=in_w-20:in_h-40,scale=960:540:flags=lanczos,setsar=1,format=yuv420p,eq=gamma=0.95" -g 50 -fflags +genpts -map 0:v -map 0:a -f tee "[select=v,a:movflags=+faststart]%stream%|[f=flv]%video%|[f=nut]pipe:" | bin\ffplay -hide_banner -loglevel 0 pipe:  -window_title "Stream Monitor 1.0 - (powered by FFPlay)  --   NOTE: closing me stops your streaming!" -x 640 -y 480  -sync audio -autoexit -exitonmousedown -autorotate
```

So this works great but i want to be able to log which file that ffmpeg has just worked on or is working on to a log file.

because i am piping to ffplay which i do NOT want to change took me too long to get it working lol plus its valuable

the reason for doing this is when i am creating my next list.txt to feed to FFmpeg i do not want to do the same file twice.

im guessing cause i am using windows it will be some extra work in pure Batch but the first step is to get the file info to a text file

I cant use > out.txt 2> err.txt is it possible to create another pipe?

I thought of using ffprobe and piping to ffmpeg but couldn't find any info on how to do that either

could i do another `tee |`  ??

I'm just lost and I can NOT find any info on the web.

Comment: You have -report in your command. The report file should have logs from the concat demuxer stating which file it has just opened.

Comment: yes but it only does it after ffmpeg is shut down, is there another way?  i want to know what was worked on so when i create a new list that file is not added to it.

Comment: i did NOt see it create the report in realtime!    do i use log level to get just the name of the video ?

Comment: It writes to the report while ffmpeg is running. You don't have to wait.

Comment: i tried adding  FFREPORT in the command and it didnt work in windows. and didnt notice that being created. until i commented.  i just want to get the files being opened.  there is way tooo much info in that report, im reading up on log levels now

Comment: because i am using windows it appears i can NOT set the log level or change the name of the log file?   it is set at log level 48 according to the log